# the_excerpt and the_content in the post of wordpress cause error

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system

I am using the **wordpress latest version** ,even I have an problem with post which contain href link is to be text on call the_excerpt (link is not working ) but when I replace the_content its working ? why and what's the reason from excerpt to content....'

Comment: Sorry but what? Also this is not the wordpress support forums here. Post the code you've got a problem with and ask your *programming* question.

Comment: kindly check i added the sample code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because the_excerpt function doesnt preserved HTML tags. Try this following solutions

http://bacsoftwareconsulting.com/blog/index.php/wordpress-cat/how-to-preserve-html-tags-in-wordpress-excerpt-without-a-plugin/

http://aaronrussell.co.uk/legacy/improving-wordpress-the_excerpt/

or use a plugin

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-excerpt/